# Is there a formula to select the active cell in which the formula is being entered?(Without VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula like this entered to cell **D5**.

***=VLOOKUP(OFFSET(D5,0,-1),Sheet1!$A$2:$B$13,2,FALSE)***

In place of **D5** next to OFFSET function, I want to put *something* such that it selects the cell in which the formula is being entered.

In my case,

[image]

Here, I want to change value in cells, **D5, D7, D9, D11, D13, D15, D17, D19, D21, D23** and **G5, G7, G9, G11, G13, G15, G17, G19, G21, G23** with respect to the value entered in the cell to the left.

It can be easily achieved by using **VLOOKUP** function but I would need to change the reference cell manually for rest of the cells.

The idea is that in this formula, **=VLOOKUP(** ***--here--*** **,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$13,2,FALSE)**, instead of using **C5, C7, C9, etc**, I need a formula to to reference the cell left to the active cell.

Comment: you should clarify what you want to lookup and maybe show us what is on your Sheet1 and the structure of that data on Sheet1

Answer (score 0):

The answer: In this Vlookup formula the lookup value refers to it's own cell minus one column. ie. the cell to the left.

```
=VLOOKUP(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1,4,1)),Sheet1!$A$2:$B$13,2,FALSE)
```

But actualy: It shouldn't be necessary to use a formula like this! You should be able to just point to C5 once, and then let excel figure out the relative position of the cell to the left, once you copy the formula to other cells: (D7, D9, D11 etc..).

```
=VLOOKUP(C5,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$13,2,FALSE)
```